# Python threading flow control in concise way

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex

I want to upload a file to two ftp sites. After both finishing, I need to delete the file.
In case not to block the main function running, both ftp and deletion functions will be implemented by threading, which means there will be 3 threads running in background simultaneously. An easy problem becomes complicated because of threading.

Following are possible solutions:

1. Use a queue and put all three threads in order
2. Use mutex

Both work, but I don't think they are the best way to do that. Can anyone share his/her idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a *semaphore*.

In your parent handler create a semaphore of 0 and hand it off to the threads.

```
import threading

sem = threading.Semaphore(0)

hostThread = threading.Thread(target=uploadToHost, args=(sem,))
backupThread = threading.Thread(target=uploadToBackup, args=(sem,))

sem.acquire() # Wait for one of them to finish
sem.acquire() # Wait for the other to finish
```

In your children, you'll just have to call `sem.release` once the upload is finished.